# Unexpected EOF in prolog at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0] in solr

Tags: solr

I am getting exception while adding batch to solrInstance. I have tested my code in different servers. It is working properly all other servers except one server.

my code is

```
SolrServer solrInstance = solrInstance1;
final Collection<SolrInputDocument> batch = new ArrayList<SolrInputDocument>(); 
            for (Doctor doctor : doctorsList) {
                SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
                String docID = doctor.getId();
                doc.addField( "_id", docID, 1.0f );
                batch.add(doc);

        }
        if (batch.size() > 0) {
            UpdateResponse upres = solrInstance.add( batch );
            upres = solrInstance.commit( true, true );
        }
```

getting exception like`

`    org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]

Can any one please help me. Is there any server setting required to submit batch

Comment: What does the log on the server side say?

Comment: this is the log i am seeing in server :: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
 at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:176)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:92)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:74)

Comment: Sounds like it's trying to load binary data as XML or something similar. What is batch defined as? What is solrInstance? Are you using SolrJ? is the javabin format enabled in Solr?

Comment: Yes we are using SolrJ. solrInstance is reference of SolrServer. batch is Collection<SolrInputDocument>. Can you please explain what is javabin and how to enable it.

Comment: Using cygwin in windows, I had this issue.  My command was forcing to ascii-text via

`curl http://server:8080/path/update?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" --data-ascii @20190308-update.xml`

But I was still having the issue until I resaved the xml in Notepad++ using "UNIX" style line returns and "UTF-8 without BOM" encoding, then the issue disappeared.